# MCMC Output does not read full vector

Tags: r, matrix, mcmc

I have a Bayesian MCMC in R, and I have the code below:

```
RWM = function(Niter,Y,X){
    p = ncol(X)
    alpha = 0.7
    beta = matrix(0,ncol=1,nrow=3)
    beta = as.matrix(beta)
    sig_p = 0
    mu_p = beta
    C = diag(p)
    R = t(chol(C))
    lpi = posterior(beta,Y,X)
    OUT = matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=Niter)
    
    for (j in 1:Niter){
      rr = rnorm(p)
        beta_p = beta + exp(sig_p) * as.vector(R%*%rr)
        lpi_p = posterior(beta_p,Y,X)
        A = exp(lpi_p-lpi)
        Acc = min(1,A)
        
        if (runif(1)<=Acc){
            beta = beta_p
            lpi = lpi_p
        }
        
        OUT[j,] = beta
        
        sig_p = sig_p + (1/j^alpha)*(Acc -0.3)
        mu_p = mu_p + (1/j)*(as.matrix(beta) - mu_p)
        bmu = as.matrix(beta - mu_p)
        C = C + (1/j)*(as.matrix(t(bmu)%*%bmu) - C)
    }
    return(OUT)
```

It looks like the vector beta will update, and the three elements in this vector will be different due to the rnorm function. However, this is not the case. The 3 columns of the output, one for each element, are exactly the same in the row. I have iterated this function out in the console several times, and in no case did the elements in beta appear to be the same.

For example: beta = [1, 2, 3] but the output = [1, 1, 1]

The MCMC iterates and does not get stuck, as the histogram shows a wide range of values in the output. It is just the sampled betas that are giving me the issue.

I'm just not understanding what is wrong with my code that prevents my vector beta from being added directly to the matrix OUT.

Comment: Is it normal that your return (`return(OUT)`) is outside the function?

Comment: I just forgot to include the last }. It's inside the function RWM, but not in the for loop. I will give that a try.

Comment: I'm also having issues with multiplying the matrixes,  it seems inconsistent on when the matrix multiplication works.. I don't know if it is just me, but I just restarted R, loaded up the same data and variables, and the function gave an error about a %*% being nonconformable